# Inalto Ceramic Cooktop Wiring

Tags: electrical

How do you hard wire an Inalto Ceramic Cooktop given the following connecting points:- L1, L2 on one side of the connecting plate and N1, N2 on the opposing side of the connecting plate, with a PE (earth) point at the bottom end of the connecting plate. I have only three wires to connect one active, one neutral and one earth. An Australian connection.

Comment: How many watts does this pull, and what's the amperage rating of the circuit you're connecting it to?

Comment: The cooktop pulls 6.0kw and the amperage of the circuit is 15amps.

Answer (score 1):

### There's just not enough power there

A 15A 240VAC circuit can only supply 3.6kW, or slightly under half of what your cooktop draws.  You'll need to have a bigger radial circuit put in, dedicated to the cooktop/cooker setup; I presume a 32A circuit would be a standard size in Australia, provided you are served with a single phase.